# Child object json string to Parent object

Tags: java, json, jackson

String JSON inheritance child to the parent object

Base class of code

```
public class A {

    int x;

    int y;

    int z;

    public A(int x, int y, int z) {

        this.x = x;

        this.y = y;

        this.z = z;

    }

}
```

Child class  :

```
public class B  extends A {
   int i;
   int j ;

   public B(int x, int y, int z, int i, int j) {

       this.i = i;

       this.j = j;

       super(x,y,z);

   }

}

B b = new B();
// converting the obj to class obj 
String s = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(b);

A a = new  ObjectMapper().convertValue(s, A.class);

B bb = (B) b;
```

I am not able to achieve this.
As a parent class doesn't have all the fields.

There is a drop in the attribute values

Object A will miss some values and not able to convert 
the parent obj to child obj.

How we can convert this properly 
Should we add  @JsonProperty

Answer (score 0):

First, you must add a public parameter-less constructor in both classes, then you can try this:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        // converting the obj to class obj
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(b);
        A a = mapper.readValue(s, A.class);

        B bb = (B) b;
```

UPDATE

You can also add an annotation to class A:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
```

And then do this:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
       // converting the obj to class obj
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(b);
        A a = mapper.readValue(s, A.class);

        B bb = (B) b;
```

Answer (score -1):

You coul add 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)  before class A declaration as below.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

class A {

 //
}
```